# How do I make a volume within a LVM survive a reboot?

Tags: linux, lvm, xenserver

I have a xenserver that has a local ISO repository created following **Inside the LVM** found at this link:

http://kb.softescu.ro/server-administration/linux-server-administration/how-to-create-a-local-iso-storage-repository-on-citrix-xenserver/

This works fine, how do I make it survive a reboot?  I'm not familiar with LVM (yet).

I'm familar with normal mounts but each time I restart it appears I have to run

```
vgchange -a y
```

as this path
/dev/VG_XenStorage-10307bc6-dc3b-6b46-b01a-b9efa6f39ae6/ISO

Doesn't exist after rebooting until after the vgchange command is run.

Unfortunately, I can't test it right now as one of the VM's will be in use for a while and I just want to be sure that if it gets restarted the ISO library will remain.
i.e. I don't want to leave it to chance.

Will adding this to /etc/fstab be all I need to do?

```
/mnt/iso_import /dev/mapper/VG_XenStorage--4031a899--4ed1--f383--4f2d--d7638260ce0e-ISO ext3 defaults 1 1
```

Comment: Maybe check out this site: http://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2005-July/msg00059.html

Answer (score -2):

If you are using suse you should look in /etc/sysconfig/lvm and on redhat && suse and other linux version volume_list in /etc/lvm/lvm.conf.

Thanks